# C++, Win32: How Do I Call a Function After Main() Exits

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-7

I have this code:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

MyEditor myEditor;
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    while(true)
    {  
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            { break; }

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            myEditor.Update();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I want to run this function right after main() exits:

```
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

The reason is that, if I call this function before the **return 0** line, "myEditor" destructor hasn't been called yet and I'm getting loads of memory leak alerts.
So I'd like to call this after my class' destructor has been called to really check if there's any leaks or not.

I've tried:

```
void CheckLeaks(void)
{
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}

//And inside the Main() block:
atexit(CheckLeaks);
```

But didn't work (actually it might've worked, but my class destructor might've not been called yet).
I know I can put my class inside the Main() block and check, but the class have to deal with the inputs and commands from the MessageProc and so I really need it global now.

OS is Windows 7 (I've found some related stuff but it seems it's for Linux only), IDE is Visual Studio 2012.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not simply allocate and de-allocate the memory for the class instance manually, using `new` and `delete`?

Comment: @enhzflep That's a great idea! Are there any side effects or cons to using dynamic memory for my class (it's kinda big since it's the whole program)?

Comment: Goody. :) I cant think of any. If it's a large class, its probably better allocated from the heap rather than the stack anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Although I don't think it's a good idea,** one way to do it would to be to create a global object and add the code in its destructor.

Generally speaking though, you should avoid problems with memory leaks by using the RAII principle wherever possible.